Why does assigning a value using a row object from iterrows() work the first time but not the second?
I have a method dotest() that returns an integer according to some random process. I am iterating over rows of a multiindexed dataframe tests and using the iterrows() row objects to assign an entry of tests a value returned by dotest(). I have been mystified to find that the assignment works the first time but not afterwards.
The output looks like this:
tranche 0: 30000 tests
                            tranche fails  fails  fails (%)  uncertainty
thickness sample size pval                                              
3         30          0.05           6214   6214      20.71         0.47
5         30          0.05           3249   3249      10.83         0.36
tranche 1: 60000 tests
                            tranche fails  fails  fails (%)  uncertainty
thickness sample size pval                                              
3         30          0.05           6214  12428      20.71         0.33
5         30          0.05           3249   6498      10.83         0.25

and all subsequent rows also have the same number for tranche fails.
When I don't go via the row object everything works as expected, but I still want to understand why this is happening. I could understand it always working or never working, but I don't understand how it can work sometimes.
Here is an abridged version of my code:
for i in range(0, tranches):
    for j, row in tests.iterrows():
        row.at["tranche fails"] = dotest(tranche_size, j[1], j[0], j[2])
        #tests.at[j, "tranche fails"] = dotest(tranche_size, j[1], j[0], j[2])
    do_other_things()
    print(tests)

I have included my full code below, and you can see a commented out line checking that this still happens if I use numpy.random.randint() so it's not a problem with dotest().
for i in range(0, tranches):
    testn = (i + 1) * tranche_size
    print(f"tranche {i}: {testn} tests")
    for j, row in tests.iterrows():
        #row["tranche fails"] = np.random.randint(10)
        row.at["tranche fails"] = dotest(tranche_size, j[1], j[0], j[2])
        #tests.at[j, "tranche fails"] = dotest(tranche_size, j[1], j[0], j[2])
    tests["fails"] += tests["tranche fails"]
    p = tests["fails"]/testn
    tests["fails (%)"] = (100*p).round(2)
    #using normal approximation of binomial distribution
    tests["uncertainty"] = (2*100*np.sqrt(p*(1-p)/testn)).round(2)
    try:
        prevtests.loc[tests.index, "fails"] += tests["tranche fails"]
        prevtests.loc[tests.index, "tests"] += tranche_size
        print(tests)
        prevtests.to_csv("Previous Tests.csv")
    except:
        pass


you should provide a sample input and your expected output

That's not full code since tranches, tranche_size, tests, and prevtests aren't defined. Please make a [mre]. In the process, you might actually find the problem yourself :) For specifics, see How to make good reproducible pandas examples.
